# boost logging: how to apply use_tss_with_cache in a filter?

Tags: logging, boost

I need to set `logging::core` by using a filter with `boost::logging::filter::use_tss_with_cache` on boost 1.60.0 or after.

Does anybody have any sample code?

Comment: Hello and welcome to [SO]! When you ask questions here, it's _really_ helpful (and would probably get you an answer faster) if you would read and follow the instructions over at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)! Also - you can make the inline-code parts of your question look nice by enclosing it in backticks (`)

Comment: Yup. Sample code, do you have it? We can look at your code if you show it, and describe what you would like added/changed. Right now we'll have to dive into the documentation to even get started. That doesn't help us help you